# How to calculate the 5th heighest salary from Employee Table and Salary Table using LINQ query

Tags: linq

Table1: EmolyeeTable

```
Eid  Ename

1    Jonh   
2    James
3    Raj
4    Tisan
5    Jack
```

Table2: SalaryTable

```
Sid   Salary  Eid

1     10000    1

2     20000    2

3     30000    3

4     40000    4

5     50000    5
```

I want to output the 5th heighest Ename and salary using a LINQ query.

O/P:

```
Ename  Salary

Jack   50000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- [`Join` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.8) to join two tables
- [`OrderBy` (`OrderByDescending`) extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8) to sort members by salary
- [`Take` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8) to take a certain number of items

**Example (you need to add adequate checks):**

```
    var q1 = from t1 in table1 join t2 in table2 on t1.EId equals t2.EId select new {t1.EName, t2.Salary};
    var q2 = q1.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Salary);
    var q3 = q2.Take(5).Select(t=>t.EName); //// In case you'd like to get Top-5 member names.
    var q4 = q2.ElementAt(4).EName //// In case you need only the 5th member name.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you are looking for Highest Salary or 5th Highest Salary. In either case, you could make use of Join and OrderBy for the purpose.

For highest Salary, you could do.

```
var result = employees.Join(salaries,e=>e.Eid,s=>s.Eid,(e,s)=> new {Name=e.EName,Salary=s.Salary})
                          .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Salary).First();
```

For 5th highest Salary, you could make use of Skip in addition to the above. For example,

```
var result = employees.Join(salaries,e=>e.Eid,s=>s.Eid,(e,s)=> new {Name=e.EName,Salary=s.Salary})
                          .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Salary).Skip(4).First();
```